# google map doesnt show any marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i was trying to use google map api v3 and pop up some markers on the map. un fortunately it doesnt show up on my map. i use array push to store marker with latitude and longitude parameter.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var trackerMarkerArray = [];

      function initialize() {

          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
          var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363800,131.044900);

        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 8
        };

        try {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng
        });

        var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng2
        });

        trackerMarkerArray.push(marker);
        trackerMarkerArray.push(marker2);

        for (var i = 0; i<trackerMarkerArray.lenght; i++){
            trackerMarkerArray[i].setMap(map);
            console.log("value" + trackerMarkerArray[i]);
        }

        } catch (err){
            alert(err);
        }


      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Comment: typo in for loop - `lenght` should be `length`

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i<trackerMarkerArray.lenght; i++)
```

lenght must be "length"

also, when the map is not showing, try to see browser's debug console for any error.